# Include whole php directory

Tags: php, include, foreach, directory

Let's say, we have index page that includes `php/common.php`.

```
foreach (glob("functions/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
}
```

Code above located in `common.php`. So `index.php` includes `common.php` and common must include all files from `functions` folder which located in the same folder with `common.php`

When I try to call some function (which located in one of `php/functions` folder's files) from `index.php` getting error message `Call to undefined function`. Used the code below  instead (to test if there is any problem with foreach loop)

```
include "functions/ipdetect.php";
```

Got result. So why foreach doesn't work in my case? Maybe php fires foreach AFTER inluding the `common.php` into `index.php`?

Comment: include("$filename."."php"); did you try that? or did you even echo $filename? Never used glob() before, just a question.

Comment: have you tried to echo out the filename before the include, so you know if your foreach actually works and which files are included?

Comment: Echoes nothing. Once more: `common.php` and `functions` folder located in same folder named `php`. So root folder looks like that `index.php; php`. Contents of `php` folder look like that `common.php; functions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you should use `include_once` it stops you from including things twice resulting in more errors, and the minor overhead does very little.

```
foreach (glob("functions/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include_once $filename;
}
```

Is the "functions" folder under the root or under the "php" folder that common is in? If under php you'll need this change:

```
foreach (glob("php/functions/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include_once $filename;
}
```

Edit removed incorrect explaination - read darren cooks comments:

@DEVastor The direct include works because it was your glob() that wasn't working, not your include().

Comment: `common.php` and `functions` folder located in same folder named `php`. So root folder looks like that `index.php; php`. Contents of `php` folder look like that `common.php; functions`

Comment: ah yip - just noticed, have a look at my update that will fix ya I think!

Comment: OK. updated the code ad it worked for me. But why i need to put path from root folder?

Comment: All files "included" are included to your `index.php` file and its path, so all sub includes need to talk about paths relative to that and not themselves. This is generally why frameworks store a constant or two containing the doc root and app root path to use instead of hoping directory structure never changes.

Comment: but why it works when i use `include "functions/ipdetect.php";` in common.php instead?

Comment: The reason you need full path is glob() works relative to the current working directory (see chdir/getcwd in the PHP manual). (This defaults to same directory as index.php, but need not be the same.) E.g. after setting up your directory structure, I confirmed it fails. If I then put `chdir("php")` above the include("php/common.inc") it works. (Which also shows that include() does _not_ use the current working directory!)

Comment: @DEVastor The direct include works because it was your glob() that wasn't working, not your include().

Answer (score 2):

Works for me (see below code - these are the full files).
Running "php index.php" from command line outputs "Hello World!".
Hint: put some global code in one of the files being included (see a.php below; uncomment the echo). That should tell you if the file is being included.
BTW, as others have said, always use include_once unless you have a good reason not to.

--- index.php ----

```
<?php
include "common.php";
echo f()."\n";
?>
```

--- common.php ---

```
<?php
foreach (glob("functions/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
}
?>
```

--- functions/a.php ---

```
<?php
//echo "*** In a.php ***\n";
function f(){
return "Hello World!";
}
?>
```

Comment: ohh.. listen I told that `common.php` and `functions` folder loacted in same folder named `php`. So root folder looks like that `index.php; php`. Contents of `php` folder look like that `common.php; functions`